# What's so great about lexical scoping?

Tags: emacs, closures, elisp, emacs24

The reason I don't understand why Emacs 24's new lexical scoping features are that great is that I can't think of any new functionality that couldn't have been implemented without them. For example, the following closure:

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
(defun f1 (num1)
  (lambda (num2)
    (setq num1 (* num1 num2))))

(fset 'f2 (f1 5))
  ==> (closure ((num1 . 5) t) (num2) (setq num1 (* num1 num2)))
(f2 5)
  ==> 25
(f2 2)
  ==> 50
```

Can be implemented with regular dynamic scoping like so:

```
(defun f1 (num)
  (let ((tmpvar (make-symbol "num")))
    (set tmpvar num)
    `(lambda (num2)
       (set ',tmpvar (* (eval ,tmpvar) num2)))))

(fset 'f2 (f1 5))
  ==> (lambda (num2) (set (quote num) (+ (eval num) num2)))
(f2 5)
  ==> 25
(f2 2)
  ==> 50
(fset 'f3 (f1 9))
  ==> (lambda (num2) (set (quote num) (+ (eval num) num2)))
(f3 3)
  ==> 27
(f3 2)
  ==> 54
(f2 10)
  ==> 500
```

Okay, so not all languages have something analogous to elisp's uninterned symbols, so I understand why lexical scoping is so great in their case. But what about elisp? Can you think of anything that I can do now (as of Emacs 24) that I couldn't do before, thanks to lexical scoping?

Comment: Of course it's *possible* to emulate lexical scoping with dynamic scoping, as you've shown, but why would you want to? Isn't the lexical scoping example easier to both write and read?

Comment: If you really want a bare-bones language that only contains "necessary" features, check out [Whitespace](http://yagni.com/whitespace/index.html). I think it should convince you there are more important things in languages that aren't strictly 'necessary' but which still help when you're programming.

Comment: It is easier to read and write it as I wrote it above, but I bet you could write a macro that makes it even easier than using a true lexical scope. At any rate, I'm just curious to know if there's anything theoretically possible with lexical scoping that's not without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have always been workarounds to simulate lexical binding in Emacs, so it's not so much about being able to do new things.

The manual says:

> Lexical binding opens up a lot more opportunities for optimization, so
>   Emacs Lisp code that makes use of lexical binding is likely to run
>   faster in future Emacs versions.  Such code is also much more friendly
>   to concurrency, which we want to add to Emacs in the near future.

I think that is the primary benefit.

The flip side to this is that dynamic binding was purposely chosen when Emacs was written for good reasons which still hold true today, and so lexical binding should certainly not be considered the New Way of doing things.

Global variables are generally considered a bad idea in programming, but Emacs is an unusual case where this doesn't really apply, because much of its immense flexibility -- one of the key things that makes Emacs great -- derives directly from dynamic binding.  Without dynamic binding, it would not be possible to bend the application to the requirements of the individual user to anything like the extent that Emacs allows.

In my opinion, lexical binding should be used cautiously and only for variables for which another user could not conceivably find a reason to override. By default variables should be `defvar`'d so that the ability to customize the behaviour (even in ways that the author did not anticipate) is preserved.

Comment: Um, no, no, and no.  Emacs was made at a time where pretty much all lisps were all dynamically scoped (except in compiled form, which is another story), specifically maclisp which elisp derives from.  So dynamic scope is certainly not "purposely chosen".  In addition, global variables behave the same in lexically scoped languages, so Emacs is not an unusual case there.  Finally, the flexibility that dynamic scope gives you is perfectly available in statically scoped languages, so that's bogus too.

Comment: @EliBarzilay RMS does not look like having chosen dynamic binding blindly, either: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-paper.html#SEC17

Comment: @DeokhwanKim: (a) Of course RMS was aware of it -- just like all lispers at the time; (b) still, he did not choose *it*, rather, he chose lisp which came with it; (c) in fact, the example in the section you point to shows exactly a kind of a bad use for dynamic scope -- one that will make Emacs throw a compilation warning for; (d) finally, the extensibility point is certainly valid (and explained nicely in the following section) in many cases including Emacs, which is why the concept of dynamically bound variables still exists in lexical languages, just not as the default for *all* bindings.

Comment: @EliBarzilay I'm not certain that he would have chosen a lexically scoped Lisp if it had been widely available at that time. From [Kent M Pitman at comp.lang.lisp](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/XnX92VXFnT4/OGD6p1Oc6qcJ), "Stallman has in the past said he very much dislikes CL's lexically scoped nature, and that the decision of emacs-lisp to stay with Maclisp-style dynamic scoping is not accidental." He *seems* to have judged dynamic scoping to be more suitable for Emacs than lexical scoping, whether or not his decision is right from the modern viewpoint.

Comment: @DeokhwanKim: Well, his decision to stick with it for the scope is obviously much more possible than his choice of it when starting the project (due to the lack of such choice).  Still, Emacs has been, for a very long time, intended to migrate to a lexically scoped language -- either Scheme or CL.  IIRC, XEmacs was leaning towards CL and GNU Emacs towards Scheme.  That's in addition to what we actually see now with Emacs getting extended with lexical scope.  But in any case debating this is not really productive -- I only intended to make the point wrt the origin of ELisp.

Comment: @EliBarzilay I should have made my point clearer. My point was that, considering RMS's paper and talk with Kent M Pitman, he seems to have been gratified with dynamic binding when designing Emacs Lisp rather than to have adoptted it reluctantly due to the lack of options. I'm not sure about that (after all, I am not RMS), but I think it is a feasible scenario.

Comment: @EliBarzilay says: "Emacs was made at a time where pretty much all lisps were all dynamically scoped (except in compiled form, which is another story), specifically maclisp which elisp derives from."* "Um, no, no, and no" - **not GNU Emacs**, which is what matters. Both Scheme and Common Lisp ***existed long before RMS created GNU Emacs***. And Common Lisp (like Emacs Lisp now) has both dynamic and lexical binding - and not just for compilation. It's just **not true** that GNU Emacs is older than is the use of lexical scoping in the most widely used Lisps.

Comment: @Drew: no, and definitely not *long*.  Consult WP and "EmacsHistory" on the wiki, and you'll see: 74-TECO+Macros, 75-Scheme, 76-Emacs, 78-Multics Emacs (first w/Lisp), 84-CL, and 85-Elisp.  So yes, Scheme is a year older than multics (leading to elisp).  Even if you fantasize about a world where Elisp in 85 is where it all started, you still have a very infant CL, and a Scheme that is still an academic toy on top of CL. Emacs is certainly younger than lexical scope, but "Scheme/CL existed *long* before Emacs" is far from true.

Comment: And yes, lexical scope *in Lisp* is indeed older, but like I said, it was mainly used in compilers, not interpreters.  See also RMS's talk from 2002, and note that none of the terms "dynamic", "lexical", and "scope" appear there, which is a hint that it wasn't a significant issue.  [And as a sidenote, I appreciate the attempt to reuse my opening, but I actually was objecting to three points, so borrowing it isn't working well.]

Comment: @EliBarzilay: Perhaps you missed (in bold) **GNU** Emacs - not just Emacs, which you refer to. Scheme was defined and in use a decade before GNU Emacs. Common Lisp was designed and widely discussed (including the use of lexical and dynamic binding) over a period of several years before GNU Emacs saw the light. And RMS was aware of and partly participated in the discussion. Common Lisp was more generally available before GNU Emacs. (E.g., I used C-L for a few years (2 implementations, UNIX & VAX) before GNU Emacs was available to me.) And Scheme as a toy on top of C-L just reverses history.

Comment: @EliBarzilay: The point is that I doubt your suggestion that RMS was unaware of lexical binding for Lisp and for that reason did not consider it for GNU Emacs Lisp - that "*dynamic scope [was] certainly not 'purposely chosen'*". Why don't you ask him? Given the discussions  at the time he designed it, I cannot imagine that he was ignorant of it. And he has since given explicit reasons why dynamic binding is something he felt (feels) is important for Emacs Lisp. IMO he did not choose it out of ignorance because "*pretty much all lisps  [at that time] were all dynamically scoped*".

Comment: Scheme was very much a toy until the very late 80s, possibly even later; "**GNU**" is just a label that came later, but read that history page for the connection between multics emacs and gnu emacs (the former is where the connection to lisp was done); and finally, I did say that he was very much aware of the dynamic scope,*and* of how it can be used as an advantage, just like any other lisper (esp. LM-people) at the time.  These days, dynamic scope is still needed for what it does -- but it's unfitting as the main default scope -- see stefan's answer.

Comment: One last comment and then I'll shut up, since this is not a good place for such discussions.  Asking the multics guy is probably better than asking RMS, but neither would be a useful source about the existence of a decision.

Comment: Instead, you should consider the world of Lisp at the time: when both premature-CL (or other full fledged lisps) and Scheme were both impractical choices; that's in addition to lexical scope *as a default* being fresh concept and people didn't know just how useful it is (witness the 30 years it took mainstream to catch on); and the fact that dynamic-scope *in* a lexical language took a while to settle in.  So whatever perceived advantage dynamic scope had was far less significance than the impracticality of a lexically scoped alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need uninterned symbols, use `cons` instead of `make-symbol`, `car` instead of `eval`, and `setcar` instead of `set` and your example will work just as well (and be more efficient).

Note also that the progression from machine-language to ever higher-level languages has been mostly based on making more and more things *impossible* (or at least much harder).  Of course those facilities taken away from the programmers were rarely used and/or considered too dangerous.  Think of using uninitialized variables (possible in C, but impossible in Java and many other languages), or jumping into the middle of an instruction.

As for some downside of your example code: not only it's less readable, but the compiler basically won't be able to know that you're constructing code, so it won't be allowed to look inside that "`(lambda ...)" to compile it, expand its macro calls, give you warnings about suspicious elements, ...

Comment: This is very helpful. Using `cons` instead of `make-symbol` does make just as much sense and is more readable. Though I notice that the cl package has a `lexical-let` macro that uses uninterned symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I think implementations of OO programming tend to fit well with lexical scope. An object with state maps rather directly to a lexical closure.

I'm sure that the CLOS implementation in common lisp leverages lexical scope heavily. It's hard for me to imagine how that spec could be implemented with dynamic scope only, but I'm sure it's possible.